# How to do Spring security with authentication token in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am building an app with spring 4 and rest web services in java.So For all web services I want to send username,password with the URL for securing the web services.Username should be "ADMIN" and password should be "ADMIN123".After hitting the service it should send  an authentication token,that value I can use for that session.

**Service class**

```
@Path("/users")
@Service
@Component
public class UserWebservice {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");  
@Autowired
UserProfileBo userProfileBo = (UserProfileBo) appContext.getBean("userProfileBo");

@Path("/")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<UserProfilePojo> fetchUserProfile() {
    ArrayList<UserProfilePojo> userProfilePojo = userProfileBo.fetch();
    return userProfilePojo;
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ABC</display-name>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.abc.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

So while now I am hitting `http://localhost:8080/ABC/users` and getting response.
But I want username and password should be added with the URL header for security.

Comment: please post some code that you have .. question of type "give me solution" are not very welcomed ..

Comment: I have added code sample.Please check it out @otopolsky

Comment: I am not an expert on spring etc.. I was just reviewing your question.. but IMHO you do not gain any security by sending username/pw via url.. or are you already https?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use token based security with Spring security, there are multiple options available.

1. Use OAuth
2. Use JWT
3. Implement own interceptor method (Not preferred)

How to implement these. Spring provides many samples for using these frameworks,

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples

Here is a good like explaining the concepts

https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java